# Comprehensive reference for print function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have searched all over but can not find a comprehensive reference and  explanation of this Python construct,

```
  print("{0} = {1}".format(key, value))
```

Comment: I don't think that's related to print function but how the `str.format` works?

Comment: Look at the [format mini-language spec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Comment: `{0:}` represents the first value, or `key`

Comment: why is this depecated in Python 3?  '{}, {}, {}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')

Comment: @user7339197 What makes you think that's "depecated"?

Comment: oh it's actually new in 2.7+, never mind

Answer (score 8):

That's all covered under string formatting, which you can read up [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Basically, the `{...}` sequences are placeholders which will use the arguments given to `format()` to construct a single result string.

These placeholders identify things such as *which* argument to use and formatting information for the argument (justification, padding, decimal places and so on).

By way of example, the following expression:

```
"{0:0>16b}".format(27)
```

gives you the value `27` in binary:

```
0000000000011011
```

That's because the format string works as follows (spaces added for readability, but they're not in the *actual* format specifier):

```
{0:0 > 16 b}
 | | | || |
 | | | |/ +-- binary
 | | | +---- width of 16
 | | +------ right justified
 | +------- zero padded
 +--------- argument zero (the first one)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a summary of the syntax by using the str method `format`:

- "{}".format(42) ==> "42"
- "{0}".format(42) ==> "42"
- "{0:.2f}".format(42) ==> "42.00"
- "{0:.0f}".format(42.1234) ==> "42"
- "{answer}".format(no_answer=41, answer=42) ==> "42"
- "{answer:.2f}".format(no_answer=41, answer=42) ==> "42.00"
- "{answer} = {answer}".format(answer=42) ==> "42 = 42"

For your example, {0} means the first argument in the `format` method which is `key` in this case and {1} means the second argument which is `value` in this case.